# How to access fields from another class

Tags: c#, wpf

Hello I have a WPF/C# application with 2 windows.
I am trying to access a

```
public int myInt;
```

in my MainWindow from my OtherWindow:

```
MainWindow.myInt =3;
```

intellisense wont even allow me to access the variable.

Could someone please help?

Comment: possible duplicate of [C#: Accessing form members from another class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717264/c-accessing-form-members-from-another-class)

Comment: You should probably learn [some basics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109.aspx) about object oriented programming.

Comment: Take a look at [MVVM](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/81484/A-Practical-Quick-start-Tutorial-on-MVVM-in-WPF).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to declare it as `static` as you don't access it via an instance, but via class name. That said, it is usually not considered good design to expose fields publicly.

Comment: i see. I guess this is off-topic, but even thought that's preached often, not making fields public, i've never seen an example showing my why.

Comment: @Laserbeak43: There should be a very popular question about this here on SO somewhere...

Answer (score 4):

You either need to have an object:

```
MainWindow mw = new MainWindow();
mw.myInt = 3
```

Or you need to make rour field static

```
public static int myInt;
```

and call it like your are already doing:

```
MainWindow.myInt =3;
```